# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name when using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: asp.net

For some reason I can not retrieve the value contained within 'CustomerAlertCountTotal'.

If I run the query using QueryBuilder (Visual Studio 2010) then the correct rows are returned, including a numerical count value/result for CustomerAlertCountTotal.

Here's my SELECT query:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCustomerList" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="REMOVED" 
    ProviderName="REMOVED" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT contact.id_contact, contact.cname, contact.caddress1, contact.caddress2, contact.caddress3, contact.caddress4, contact.caddress5, contact.cpostcode, contact.ctel, contact.cmobile, contact.cemail, contact.trading_id, contact.cposition, trading_name.trading_name, CustomerAlertCountTotal FROM contact INNER JOIN trading_name ON contact.trading_id = trading_name.id_trading_name LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(AlertID) AS CustomerAlertCountTotal, AlertTradingID FROM customer_support_dev.customer_alerts) AS COUNT ON COUNT.AlertTradingID = contact.trading_id WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(contact.cname) > 0) ORDER BY contact.cname">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Or slightly easier to read:

```
SELECT contact.id_contact, contact.cname, contact.caddress1, contact.caddress2, contact.caddress3, contact.caddress4, contact.caddress5, contact.cpostcode, contact.ctel, contact.cmobile, contact.cemail, contact.trading_id, contact.cposition, trading_name.trading_name, CustomerAlertCountTotal
FROM contact
INNER JOIN trading_name ON contact.trading_id = trading_name.id_trading_name
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(AlertID) AS CustomerAlertCountTotal, AlertTradingID
FROM customer_support_dev.customer_alerts) AS COUNT ON COUNT .AlertTradingID = contact.trading_id
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(contact.cname) > 0)
ORDER BY contact.cname
```

And this is how I'm trying to display the value:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustomerAlertCountTotal" SortExpression="CustomerAlertCountTotal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <em><%#Eval("CustomerAlertCountTotal")%></em>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If I replace this:

```
<em><%#Eval("CustomerAlertCountTotal")%></em>
```

With this:

```
<em><%#Eval("cemail")%></em>
```

Then I see their email address where the total CustomerAlertCountTotal value should be so I know the page code is essentially sound but for some reason, it appears that CustomerAlertCountTotal is not actually being selected as a usable value - yet it shows the count result fine in querybuilder??

Comment: Additional thought, could this be because CustomerAlertCountTotal isn't an actual/real column in the DB (because I'm using AS)?

Comment: The plot thickens.. I changed AutoGenerateColumns="False" to be True on my GridView and took a look at what was returned. All columns are there, except the very last one CustomerAlertCountTotal. Is this because I am using an OUTER JOIN?